# To get console access to windows instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Earlier, I was able to access windows ec2 instance through RDP session but suddenly my RDP got disconnected as in server manager -> Local Server -> Remote Desktop got disabled due to which I am not able to login to the instance. How do I get console access so as that I can troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question does not have enough detail for us to be able to assist with an Answer. What error are you receiving? Have you checked whether the IP address has changed? Does it fail quickly, or does it take some time before the error appears? Please Edit your question to provide additional details so that we can help you.

Comment: Yes, I have checked, IP address is unchanged. Just want to know is it possible to get  console access for instance  other than RDP so as to troubleshoot the issue